# Using Gazebo Simulator with Pioneer3dx Model

Tags: gazebo, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written code that I have run on MobileSim simulator for the Pioneer3dx model, and it runs on the actual robot, which used RosAria. Now I am trying to use the Gazebo simulator, since I need to use the physics engine, but I am getting really confused. I have looked online and gone through the Gazebo ROS tutorials but I still am not quite clear on what I need to do. Can I use ROS Aria in Gazebo? If so, how? If not, is there anything special I need for gazebo? How will I convert the code I had written for the robot using ROS Aria to the format Gazebo needs (because my code subscribes to topics such as /RosAria/pose and /RosAria/sonar, which will not not exist when ROS Aria is not running)? I am sorry for the million questions!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215815/using-gazebo-simulator-with-pioneer3dx-model/) by [thumper](https://answers.ros.org/users/23555/thumper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosaria` can only communicate with either the Pioneer robot, or MobileSim which emulates the Pioneer robot.  To use Gazebo, set up your launch configuration such that your client nodes connect to Gazebo's ROS interface rather than `rosaria`.  Gazebo's `libgazebo_ros_diff_drive` plugin implements a differential drive controller with a similar ROS interface as `rosaria` (i.e. `cmd_vel`, `odom` topics, `base_link`, etc.).  If you want to try the Gazebo and URDF configuration from https://github.com/MobileRobots/amr-ros-config and provide any feedback (via github or the ros-sig-pioneer mailing list), that would be very helpful for improving it.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2017-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1